# tkinter on Raspberry Pi; Raspbian/Jessie Python 3.4

Tags: raspbian, python, tkinter

I installed **tkinter** using the following request:
`sudo apt-get install python3-tk`

When I try to import the module using:

```
 #!/usr/local/lib/python3.4  
 import tkinter as tk
```

The above two lines resulted in the following error condition (both IDLE and python3 shell)

```
ImportError: No module named tkinter
```

Wits end! - Any insight much appreciated. Thx Tankadere

Comment: have you also installed `tk-dev` package?
`sudo apt-get install tk-dev`. Also try changing the shebang line to `#!/usr/bin/python3.4`

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue and realized I was using the command

```
python
```

when instead I should be using this command

```
python3
```

If you use 2.7,

```
import Tkinter # capital T
```

if you use 3.4,

```
import tkinter # lowercase t
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `import Tkinter`, not `import tkinter`, because Python is case-sensitive and Tkinter was renamed in latest verisons.

Comment: `Tkinter` is actually for python 2 and `tkinter` is for python 3. So according to OP's query `tkinter` should be right

Comment: Hmm, strange, I remembered that Tkinter was renamed to tkinter only in some of updates to Python3... Gonna try it now.

Answer (score -1):

On Fedora 25, `dnf install python3-tkinter`.